# Tomcat 404 even though all operations are performed

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.x.
Following is my method signature.

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces("application/json")
 public Response createUser(UserObject UserDetails, @Context ContainerRequestContext requestContext){

//Opeations

}
```

When I run this on my local machine with tomcat I am getting `200` as my status.

But when I deploy this to my server. I am getting `404` even though all the operations (Validations and DB entries) are performed in the back end.

I am not able to understand this weird behavior.

What might be the issue, since every thing is working fine on my local machine.

Comment: On which server you are deploying? check proxy setting,also you need to cinfigure yourapplication url in the server.

Comment: I am using tomcat server. I am not using any proxy.Other API's are working perfectly fine.

Comment: If you're seeing the request and all operations are performed then perhaps you're inadvertently setting the status code of your response to 404. Please show the code that builds the response, particularly the code that sets the response status code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall
We had such problem earlier and it was from the firewall which prevent some pages from going up
Other problem could from missing jars (jdbc...) so check also your log